# Multiple values against same condition

Tags: c#, optimization

Is there any other way to optimize the below code? I feel the below code is huge for the operations it performs.

```
if ((currentElement == null ||
    (firstGridRow["Low"].ToString() == string.Empty || 
    firstGridRow["High"].ToString() == string.Empty ||
    firstGridRow["Mean"].ToString() == string.Empty ||
    firstGridRow["StdDev"].ToString() == string.Empty)))
{
    continue;
}

if (newRow.Length != 0)
{
    AddColorList(currentElement, opid, currentLow, "Low", newRow, listCollectionLow);
    AddColorList(currentElement, opid, currentHigh, "High", newRow, listCollectionHigh);
    AddColorList(currentElement, opid, currentMean, "Mean", newRow, listCollectionMean);
    AddColorList(currentElement, opid, currentStdDev, "StdDev", newRow, listCollectionStdDev);
}
```

Comment: You should ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ !!

Comment: What is firstGridRow? And how loop looks like?

Comment: Why are you checking `firstGridRow["Low"]` and the other columns on every loop iteration even if it is always the same row?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: Asked this over there. But no response for a long time. So asked here.

Comment: @RanjithKumarGovarthanan: [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ, like this:

```
private static readonly string[] AllKeys = new[] {"Low", "High", "Mean", "StdDev"};


if (currentElement == null || ALlKeys.Any(k => gridRow[k].ToString() == string.Empty)) {
     ...
}
if (newRow.Length != 0) {
    foreach (var key in AllKeys) {
        AddColorList(currentElement, opid, currentLow, key, newRow, listCollectionLow);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can utilize string.IsNullOrEmpty(gridRow[key]) here

Comment: @Tobias Correct. The `string` is never `null`, though, so I am not sure if that would be of much use here.

Comment: Where does it say `string` is never `null` ?

Comment: @Tobias It comes from `ToString()`. Although the guidelines do not prohibit `ToString()` from returning `null`, in practice it never does.

Comment: If gridRow[key] is null you will get an exception because ToString() cannot be called on a null object. The ToString() will not return null, that is true, but calling it on a null object surely will throw an exception.

Comment: @Tobias The same would happen in the original code, though, so the conversion is OK.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I could not understand this piece of code 'if (currentElement == null || ALlKeys.Any(k => gridRow[key].ToString()'. do i need to loop through to get the value of 'key' which you speicified here?

Comment: @RanjithKumarGovarthanan No, LINQ does the iteration for you. You need to add `using System.Linq` at the top for this to compile.

Comment: Thanks. I hope you had done typo error instead of 'k' in gridRow[k] you specified gridRow[keys]?

Comment: @RanjithKumarGovarthanan Yes, I wanted to name it `key` first, but then shortened to `k`, and forgot to fix it in the other spot. Thanks!